# C# and word interop with citrix leads to crash

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, citrix

I have an application at my hands that should copy a Word-file, open the copy, search/replace a number of values in the document and save it. Works fine using Office-Interop with either VB6 or C# . Now, the end-user has a citrix-setup and here the command to open the document crashes the calling application.

Here is some C#-example-code up to the point where it throws an exception :

```
try
{
    app = new ApplicationClass();
    app.Visible = true;

    object fileName = @"C:\some_document.doc";
    object readOnly = false;
    object isVisible = app.Visible;
    object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    doc = app.Documents.Open(ref fileName,
                ref missing, ref readOnly,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref isVisible,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
}
```

The message is "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.". The error occurs at the Open-Command.

As stated before, everything runs fine as long as Word is not started over Citrix.

Now, what are my options? I'd love to know why this happens and what could be changed so i could use the existing code that edits the docs. I'd use a library to do the search and replace without using Word at all, so i'd be glad to get hints on products i could use. Since i'm not looking for something fancy here i dont't want to invest lots of money though.

Oh, these are DOC-files, no DOCX!

I forgot to mention: doing something similar with Excel and Interop does work! That's what urks me the most!

Answer (score 1):

Office Interop is NOT supported by MS in "server-like scenarios" (which Citrix is IMHO a special kind of)... see http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2

Your options include several libtraries (free and commercial) - for example:

- [MS OpenXML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124) (free)
- [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx) (commercial)

**UPDATE - after the EDIT of the OP**:

MS indicates that it is NOT supported (neither for Word not for Excel!), this doesn't mean that it can't work - only that you can't rely on it to work... since you write that you use `DOC` (not `DOCX`) I suspect you are stuck with commercial libraries like the one I mentioned above... for Excel there are also commecial option available like Aspose.Cells, Flexcel, SpreadsheetGear...

Comment: OpenXML only works with docx-files, so this is no option for me. The other option looks nice but very expensive.

Comment: Isn't the reason for 'not supporting' that they can't guarantee that no popup might appear when using interop and that in a server (noconsole) setup there would be no way to dismiss such a dialog ?

Comment: @Eddy there are several other reasons (one of them is the one you mentioned)... please follow the first link in my answer, MS goes into great detail about the reasons...